# Issue with NULL value in nested case

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql

Long story short i need to return a varchar value if stored value is null but eithers bring me a NULL value or  varchar value here is the code.

in the table i have some fields null and some with data

```
CASE WHEN DS.DBIRTH+DS.MBIRTH+DS.YBIRTH = 
'' THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),PT.CLIENTDBIRTHDATE,111)
ELSE 'INPUT DATE OF BIRTH'
CASE WHEN PT.CLIENTBIRTHDATE IS NULL THEN ''
 ELSE '1800-01-01'
 END 
 END AS BFIELD
```

this brings me something like this

```
         NULL
        1917/05/02
         NULL
        1923/02/02
        1967/01/05
        NULL
```

but i need something like this

```
        01/01/1800
        1917/05/02
        01/01/1800
        1923/02/02
        1967/01/05
        01/01/1800
```

sorry for the ultra noob question

Comment: The cases are not correctly nested (probably); MySQL might be trying to concatenate the result of the inner case on to the end of the 'INPUT DATE OF BIRTH' string.

Comment: you could use the ifnull like IFNULL(PT.CLIENTDBIRTHDATE,'1800-01-01')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your current `case` statement looks off.  I imagine what you want to do is wrap the result in `coalesce`:

```
COALESCE(CASE 
             WHEN DS.DBIRTH+DS.MBIRTH+DS.YBIRTH = '' 
             THEN CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),PT.CLIENTDBIRTHDATE,111)
             ELSE 'INPUT DATE OF BIRTH'
         END, '01/01/1800') AS BFIELD
```

Answer (score 0):

Without the Case statement it should be something as simple as....

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10) , 
                CAST(ISNULL(DateColumn,'01/01/1800') AS DATE)
                ,111)
```